# Sample variance of a random sample from a normal distribution with mean and variance

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, variance

I know that if the sample variance of a random sample from a normal distribution $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is

$$S_1^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum{(X_i-\bar{X})}^2$$

then,

$$U =\frac{(n-1)S_1^2}{\sigma^2}$$ has a $\chi^2$ distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

Does this mean that if my sample variance of a random sample from a normal distribution $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is

$$S_2^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum{(X_i-\bar{X})}^2$$

then,

$V  =  \dfrac{nS_2^2}{\sigma^2}$, has a $\chi^2$ distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom?

Comment: If you had asked about $\dfrac{n S_1^2}{\sigma^2}$ then it would have a $\chi^2$ distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom, as it would be equal to your original $U$.  If you had defined $S_2^2= \dfrac1n \sum (X-\mu)^2$ then $\dfrac{n S_2^2}{\sigma^2}$  would have a $\chi^2$ distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom

Comment: Thank you, I did made a mistake on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Not quite.  In general, the sample variance
$$
S^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^2,
$$
given $X_i\overset{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim}\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, is distributed according to $S^2\sim\operatorname{Gamma}(\tfrac{n-1}{2},\tfrac{2\sigma^2}{n-1})$ (shape-scale parameterization). Through a slight abuse of notation we write
$$
S^2\sim \operatorname{Gamma}(\tfrac{n-1}{2},\tfrac{2\sigma^2}{n-1})
$$
$$
\tfrac{n}{\sigma^2}S^2\sim \tfrac{n}{\sigma^2}\operatorname{Gamma}(\tfrac{n-1}{2},\tfrac{2\sigma^2}{n-1})
$$
$$
\tag{1}
\tfrac{n}{\sigma^2}S^2\sim\operatorname{Gamma}(\tfrac{n-1}{2},\tfrac{2n}{n-1}).
$$
The right hand side of $(1)$ cannot be written as a simple $\chi^2$-distribution as it is equivalent to
$$
\tfrac{n}{\sigma^2}S^2\sim\tfrac{n}{n-1}\underbrace{\operatorname{Gamma}(\tfrac{n-1}{2},2)}_{\chi^2(n-1)},
$$
which is to say $\tfrac{n}{\sigma^2}S^2$ has the same distribution as a $\chi^2(n-1)$ random variable multiplied by $n/(n-1)$.

Comment: Does this mean that $\tfrac{n}{\sigma^2}S^2$ has a ${\chi^2}$-distribution with n-1 degrees of freedom?

Comment: No, the last line means $\tfrac{n}{\sigma^2}S^2$ has the same distribution as a $\chi^2(n-1)$ random variable multiplied by $n/(n-1)$.

Comment: I see, thank you so much.

Comment: @cronky $\tfrac{n}{\sigma^2}S_1^2$ - note the subscript - would be equal to $\tfrac{n-1}{\sigma^2}S^2$ and so  would have  a $\chi^2$
-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom